# Permutation Problem involving repetitions in the number of things to be chosen from and the number of slots being unequal to the number of things

Tags: permutations

Problem:
A person has one white, two red, and three green flags. How many different signals can they make, each containing four flags arranged one above the other?

My attempt:

We have 4 slots and 6 things to choose from. But among the 6 things, there are repetitions. I know how to account for repetitions when there are same number of things to choose from as the number of slots: no. of permutations is $$ = \frac{n!}{p! \times q! \times r!}$$ [given that there are p number of repetitions of first kind, q number of repetitions for second kind, and r number of repetitions for third kind]. How can I account for repetitions in this case?

Comment: I think you just have to list the possibilities systematically.  Note that there must be at least $1$ green flag, so how many signals use $3$ green flags, $2$ green flags, $1$ green flag?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, that's one way of doing it. But shouldn't there be a formula for it?

Comment: I don't think so.  Why should there be a formula?